# R: Adding data from different rows to other rows

Tags: r, row, addition

Currently, I have managed to clean and merged my data to only contain those variables/observations of interest that I want. However, I really want to add all the N85 and N_unknown data to the respective N80_84 years.

[head of data.frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LTRo.png) <- the col names

[rows I want to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKYsb.png) <- the rows I want to add in the above example.

For eg, I want to add YEAR 1986 (col 1), for **age groups N85** (col2) data to the respective YEAR 1986, **age groups N80_84**.

Like row 13 + row 96 = newN80_84 in year 1986; row 11 + row 105 = new80_84 in year 1987 etc.

Is there a code for that? To add to their respective years and not a lump sum? I wanted to use `rowSums()`, but it doesn't add specifically to their respective years.

Also, I only wanted to add cols 3 and 4, not the last column with 500 as values. Is it possible to "specify" which cols to add?

Comment: It is always good to provide reproducible example using dput() in r. please provide a proper example

Answer (score 0):

Using [mtcars dataset](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/mtcars.html) you can add two specific columns as follows:

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

So you can add **mpg** column to **cyl** column and then add it to your dataframe as shown below:

```
newcol <- c(mtcars['mpg']+mtcars['cyl']) # by using column names
# or by using column number you can add as follows:
newcol <- mtcars[,1]+mtcars[,2]
newdf=cbind(mtcars,newcol)
head(newdf)
                  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  newcol
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 27.0
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 27.0
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 26.8
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 27.4
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 26.7
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 24.1
```

You can see new column named mpg added at the end of the dataframe.